# Prove that there exists $N$ different points $P_i$ such that not all of them are on the same line and their distance is $d(P_i,P_j) \in \Bbb N$

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

> Let $N>2$ be a number ($N \in \Bbb N$) prove that there exists $N$ different points $P_i$ such that not all of them are on the same line and the distance between them is $d(P_i,P_j) \in \Bbb N$ for all $1 \leq i \leq j \leq N$

---

I always post my way organized and everything I tried but here I could not do it well as I have ideas in my mind but I do not know how to actually start this proof(the proof is not related to any topic I study it was just a fun question my professor gave).

first I tried to understand why it cannot be $N=1$ and thought that it is probably because of pythagorean theorem since we will get $1^2+1^2=C^2= \sqrt{2} \not \in \Bbb N$ and the same thing for $N=2$ but I am not sure that this is the reason as there are infinite numbers that do the same (where the result is not natural).

I thought about placing all the points on the $X$ axis except for oneto put it on point $(0,y)$ and from this point to pull a straight line to every other point and then maybe a triangle are will be an answer? or anything related to a triangle that I cannot quiet figure.

sorry for the picture but this is what I thought about:

[image]

I could not continue or even start the actual proof but this is my idea.

Note - I do not study this topic so if someone can help hopefully the explanation can be simple , Thank you for any tips and help

Edit - according to the comments the reason for $N=1,2$ is not possible because then they can be on the same line.

the question is related to pythogrean triples and the idea in the picture is correct.

$(a,b,c)=(2mn,m^2-n^2,m^2+n^2)$ will give us triples and the area of the triangle is $mn(m^2-n^2)$ but I am not able to put it in a generalized way and prove the question.. the idea is now understandable and more clear thanks to Jason DeVito but as mentioned I am not able to put it in a general way

Comment: The issue for $N=1$ and $N=2$ is that for these $N$, the statement "not all of them are on the same line" is false for any configuration.  To say this another way, given any $2$ points, they *do* lie on one line, and any one point lies on the same line (as itself).  Once you get $N\geq 3$ points, it's possible for them to not all like on one single line.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Thank you , then what I said is just not correct for 3 points with distance 1 unit

Comment: Right.  In terms of another hint:  Your picture is a good way to tackle the problem.  What do you know about Pythagorean triples?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I am not sure if this is what you mean but I know that for $x^2+y^2=z^2$ we have $\frac{z}{y}=\frac{m^2+n^2}{2mn}$ where $m,n \in \Bbb Z$ and $\frac{x}{y}=\frac{m^2-n^2}{2mn}$ 
so $m,n$ cannot be both even and cannot be both odd

Comment: That's a great start.  Notice your picture includes a ton of right triangles, all having a vertical side from $0$ to $2$, and a horizontal side at various points along the $x$-axis.   So, basically what you're looking for is a long list of Pythagorean triples which all have the same $y$-value.   Do you see how to get that from your formulas?

Comment: Is this question specifically asking for points in the plane? Otherwise if you are allowed N-dimensional points, you can choose $P_i$ to lie on the $i$th axis with length $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @HermanChau It is specifically in the plane 2-dimensional

Comment: Even vs. odd isn't the relevant thing.  Take $y$ to be of the form $y = 2mn$ where $y$ has many other decompositions as $y = 2 m' n'$ with $m'\neq n'$.  E.g., $y= 72$ can be written as $y = 2 \cdot 9\cdot 4 = 2\cdot 12\cdot 3 = 2 \cdot 18\cdot 2 = 2\cdot 36\cdot 1$, so $y = 72$ is the height of 4 primitive right triangles with integer side lengths.  This solves the $N=5$ case.  Can you see how to generalize this for general $N$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito I know that $(a,b,c)=(2mn,m^2-n^2,m^2+n^2)$ and the area of the triangle is $mn(m^2-n^2)$ but I am not able to put it in a generalized way and prove the question.. if I use $y=2m'n'$ for example how do I continue from here? I cannot write it in a different way as you did with $y=72$
thank you

Comment: For example choose $y=2^{2N+1}$, $m_k=2^k$ and $n_k=2^{2N-k}$ for $k=1, \ldots, N-1$, $P_k=(m_k^2-n_k^2, 0) $, $P_N=(0, y) =(0,2m_k\cdot n_k) $

Comment: You just need to pick and repick $y$ with more and more factors.  @Jochen suggested one fine way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pythagorean triples indeed help with finding the solution, and line plus a point provides one example. Another one, in my opinion slightly more elegant, is a circle.

So let us look at points on the unit circle. For each angle $\theta$, the point $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ lies on the unit circle. For some particular $\theta$, both coordinates of this point will be rational – indeed, points of form $\left(\frac{m^2-n^2}{m^2+n^2},\frac{2mn}{m^2+n^2}\right)$ are rational and lie on the unit circle (this is where we use Pythagorean triples). Let $S$ be the set of all such $\theta$.

What is particularly useful about $S$ is that it is closed under addition. Indeed, we can express $\cos(\theta + \phi)$ and $\sin(\theta+\phi)$ by $\cos \theta$, $\sin \theta$, $\cos \phi$ and $\sin \phi$, which are rational numbers whenever $\theta,\phi \in S$. We also have a useful property $\theta \in S \iff -\theta \in S$.

Now the distance between $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and $(\cos \phi, \sin \phi)$ is the same as the distance between $(\cos (\theta-\phi), \sin(\theta-\phi))$ and $(1,0)$ – this is just rotation by $\phi$. Thus instead of proving "any two points coming from $S$ have rational distance" we can prove "any point coming from $S$ has a rational distance from $(1,0)$". The only issue is that it is not true, but let's do necessary calculations anyway. Distance between $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ and $(1,0)$ is equal to

$$ \sqrt{(\cos \theta - 1)^2 + \sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{\cos^2 \theta - 2 \cos \theta + 1 + \sin^2 \theta} = \sqrt{2 - 2 \cos \theta}. $$

This does not have to be rational, but if we remember that $\cos \theta = 2 \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2} - 1$, we can write the expression above as $2 \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \frac{\theta}{2}}$, which is $2\sin \frac{\theta}{2}$.

Thus, if we take the set of points $(\cos 2 \theta, \sin 2 \theta)$ where $\theta \in S$, then any two points are in rational distance from each other.

To solve your problem, just choose $N$ points from this set, and scale the picture up by the common denominator, so that instead of rational distances we have integer distances.

Comment: Oh, I see in the meantime someone posted a similar solution, just one copied from wikipedia. You can find more interesting features of this problem on the wiki page of Erdős–Ulam problem.

Comment: Thank you , it is understandable just I did not understand what you mean by "To solve your problem, just choose N points from this set, and scale the picture up by the common denominator, so that instead of rational distances we have integer distances." what do you mean by scale the picture up by the common denominator? can you give an example? I do not know what that means even after searching (probably because its in English but an example would help)

Comment: Well, let's see what happens for $N=2$. Let's say we have points $(1,0)$ and $(\frac{7}{25},\frac{24}{25})$ (the second one is the double of (4/5,3/5)). The distance between them is 6/5, which is not an integer. But you can scale the picture in zero to make it five times larger – so you get points $(5,0)$ and $(\frac{7}{5},\frac{24}{5})$, with distance 6.

If you have more points, you just need, instead of scaling five times, scale by (let's say) product of all denominators – after multiplying they will vanish for sure.

Answer (score 2):

**Claim.** There is an infinite set of points on the unit circle such that the distance between any two of them is rational.

*Proof.* Parametrise by $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and consider the set $S$ of all points where $\tan\frac{\theta}{4}\in\mathbb Q$. Half angle formulae then imply that $\sin\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$ are rational too.

For two points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and $(\cos\phi,\sin\phi)$ belonging to $S$, their distance is given by
$$\sqrt{2(1-\cos(\theta-\phi))}=2\left|\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}-\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\right|=2\left|\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\phi}{2}-\sin\frac{\phi}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}\right|\in\mathbb Q.$$
So $S$ satisfies the claim. $\square$

Now we can just pick $N$ points belonging to $S$, scale up by a suitable common denominator and we are done.